# Scripts external to WordPress cause 404 errors

Tags: server, 404-error, configuration

I installed WordPress in the root of my web site. Everything went well.

But now, other scripts and files, totally unrelated to WordPress, in other folders, cause WordPress 404 errors. For instance, I copied Docuwiki to a folder called example.com/docuwiki and when I try to run the install.php file from there, I get a 404 error.

Is there any way to work around this, other than moving Wordpress to a different directory?

Comment: Your question is very vague and therefore hard to answer. Without additional facts, others can only guess what you have configured wrong on your server.

Answer (score 1):

My money would be on the .htaccess of your root directory is trying to route the /docuwiki request through Wordpress, which is why it is failing.

Your .htaccess file should look something like [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Creating_and_editing_.28.htaccess.29):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```